# How to set Chrome Shortcuts as priority over web app?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, website, navigation

I'd think Google built in shortcuts have priority over any web app. However one I'm using uses some Google shortcuts for it's own purposes. I'm talking about [iDashboards](https://www.idashboards.com) specifically, and this app has no possible configuration to change it's shortcuts, so I think there's a way to tell Chrome to have a greater priority over the app as it's the browser...

Examples of this are:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> - <kbd>9</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd>

I use them to constantly navigate between tabs: This web app forces me to use the mouse when I'm using it and it's annoying.

Can someone help me?

THANKS!